# Where I can download source code of Music Player of android?

Tags: android, android-source

I cannot access http://android.git.kernel.org/. So where can I download the source code of the Music Player default of android?
I'm using android 2.2.1

**Edit:**
Android source now can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is also on https://github.com/android

Answer (score 0):

**Media player in android:**

You can download a source code in 
[Android hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)